# CKEditor, TinyMCE or any Rich Text Editor in jQuery popup

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, tinymce, ckeditor

I am developing an ASP.NET web application in which I am going to use CKEditor or any other rich text editor in the jQuery pop up, but the problem is this, I don't know anything about the jQuery pop up. I have visited [this link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ckeditor-in-ui-dialog) but can't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery UI Dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). To do this, just include jQueryUI in your html.

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.17.min.js"></script>
```

You can then make the dialog using jQuery as follows:

```
var txt = '<div class="my-dialog-div"> <textarea id="myTextField"/></div>';

var $dialog = $(txt)
.dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Add Annotation" : function() {
            // My function definition
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['myTextField'];
        if (editor) {
            editor.destroy(true);
        }
    }
});

$('#myTextField' ).ckeditor();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use CKEditor for Asp.net follow http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor.NET_released.